# terraform : Getting Mange access details for data lake containers

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

[image]

In terraform script , Suppose I want to display the all users, groups and service principles of the container through terraform how to achieve this. Please share the inputs for the same. Am able to display only few attributes of this container but not all . [image]

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem? Do not keep silent. I'm helping you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you have seen are all things you can get via the Terraform. Terraform is a poor tool and it does not support a lot of features for Azure. You can use the Azure CLI to get the users, and if you really want to get them through Terraform, you can run the CLI inside Terraform Local-exec:

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command= <<EOF
            az storage fs access show --account-name storage_name -p path -f container_name
        EOF
    }
}
```

And the result will look like this:

[image]

It shows you all the users' object Id and the permissions they have.